# architectural design for REST API with views across resources

Tags: rest

Looking for some input on a REST API architectural design. I often find that the desired data is the combination of a view across multiple resources. Would you expect the client to combine them, or provide an API that does the combination for the client?

For example, let's say we are writing a REST API for people to become notified about events. Someone will indicate interest in an event in one of 2 ways:

- Join an organization that regularly puts on events that the person has interest in
- Search for and then mark a particular event run by an organization I wouldn't normally subscribe to

I can retrieve all of the events for user `100` by doing the following long steps:

1. `GET /user/100/organizations` returns `123`
2. `GET /organizations/123/events` returns `[15,16,20]`
3. `GET /user/100/savedevents` returns `[35,36]`
4. `GET /events/15,16,20,35,36` returns all of the events

But that seems rather heavy for a client. I almost want a client to be able to say, "give me all of the interesting events for this user":

```
GET /user/100/events
```

...and then require the server to understand that it has to go through all of steps 1-4 and return them, or, at the very least, return `[15,16,20,35,36]` so it becomes 2 steps: get event IDs; get event details.

Does this even make sense, to make a view that cuts across multiple resources that way?

EDIT: To explain further. My hesitation is because I can see how `/organizations/123/events` is a clean resource; if is identical to saying `/events?organizations=123`, i.e. "give me resource events where organizations=123". Same for `/user/100/organizations`.

But `/user/100/events` is **not** "give me resource events where organizations=123". It is "give me organizations registrations where user=100, retrieve those organization ids, then give me the events where the organization=123, then give me savedevents where user=100."

Each of the three steps itself is a clean resource mapping. Putting them together seems messy. But so does asking a client (especially a Web client), to figure out all that logic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be several ways to solve this... however, I think that most of the times (if the service is managed by the same provider) it is better to have the logic on the server-side and make REST calls as independent as possible of each other (i.e., the server performing the multiple operations required - normally read data from DBs that are store the data handled in the API resources).

In the example you talk about this would mean your REST API would expose a "user" resource and a sub-resource "events" (which you call "savedevents") he is interested in. With this in mind you would have something like this:

- `POST /user/{username}/events` stores a new event (or multiple events) the user is interested in
- `GET /user/{username}/events` returns all the events the user is interested in
- `GET /user/{username}/events/{eventid}` returns details of a specific event

To "filter" user events per organization (and other filtering operations) you can use "query parameters":

- `GET /user/{username}/events?organization=123`

So, the server (or API call) would perform the operations you describe from step 1 to step 4 in the `GET /user/{username}/events`. You can still make the other resources ("organizations" and "events") in your API, however they would be used in other contexts (like store new events or organizations, etc.).

HTH

Comment: So by your logic, `POST /user/:user/events` doesn't create a new event (that is done at `POST /organization/:org/events` since events belong to an organization), but stores the ID of an event that is of particular interest to the user. However, `GET /user/:user/events` is supposed to return all of the events saved in `POST /user/:user/events` **and** events that are part of an organization for which the user signed up. Does that still work?

Comment: You know, there is some part of me that says, "if it is this complex, I am thinking about it wrong." I could always do it differently: when a user signs up for an org, all of their events are (as if) `POST`ed to the user events, but that leads to lots of data duplication and risk of missing something.

Comment: Yes, I do think that is the idea. User "likes" and "event", but the actual details of the event are stored in/via the `/organization/:event/`... I understand your reasoning that `GET /user/:user/events` seems to have a different "logic" (namely retrieving full details of the event - not only the even ID)... however it does seem to me  that it is better from the client perspective than having to get the details in another call to the specific details of the event... but I can see your concern.

Comment: Actually, my concern is more to do with the fact that it has to retrieve different kinds of events. I don't mind at all that `GET /user/:user/event` retrieves IDs. I *do* mind that it retrieves events that come from different places: `POST /user/:user/event` ("like" an event), or just because I "like" an organization and it created an event. I like your analog of "like" an event.

Comment: But I agree with you, bad form to leave it to the client to piece it all together.

Comment: Concerning the `GET /user/:user/event` retrieving events "that come from different places", please check my updated response... you can use "query parameters" to filter them our "per organization", for example.

Comment: I still think your approach is cleanest though. `GET /user/:user/events` means "give me the events that are relevant for this user."

Comment: I also think this is a good approach... I think the only inconsistency, if we can call that, is the fact we store the "likes" (or IDs of events the user likes) and retrieve (on the GET) the details of the events... but maybe this is still a very reasonable assumption.

Comment: Been thinking about that myself. Might be cleaner if the `POST` requires a parameter, e.g. `{like:true}` or similar, and then the `GET` retrieves both kinds, so at least it is somewhat cleaner. Still, closest I have seen to something reasonable.

Comment: Know what the hard part is now? Every other resource either maps to a direct item in the DB, or to another resource (with params) that maps to a direct item in the DB. E.g. `/events` is an event in the DB, and `/org/:org/events` is just a special form of `/events?org=123`. Because of that, *everything* was straight framework, configurable. Now I need to add custom logic. Ugh.

Comment: In the end, I took your approach. What finally triggered it was the abstraction. By doing `GET /user/:user/events`, I am getting all of the events for the user, independent of where they come from (although I can always filter it later). That allows me to abstract it under the covers: I can have it pull from the various sources and weave them together; I can push events into the user queue and just present; I have lots of options, which this approach leaves me free to pursue without changing client interfaces.

Comment: Happy it helped, I think it is a good/balanced approach for the constraints you mention... the "beauty" (and at the same time "problem") of REST "architecture style" is that it still leaves room for "interpretation"... one needs to take some decisions and assumption from time to time that are not so directly mapped to the general principles.

Comment: BTW, it worked out quite nicely. I use a framework in express/nodejs that automatically creates all of the REST resources. Just needed to set up custom handling for one resource - which the framework supports - and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit confused by your question, so I'll try to be as comprehensive as possible and hopefully I'll have hit on an answer you need =P.

> I often find that the desired data is the combination of a view across
>   multiple resources. Would you expect the client to combine them, or
>   provide an API that does the combination for the client?

In a true RESTful environment all cross-sectional views of data would be done by the server, not by the client.

The primary reason for a RESTful design is allow access to the CRUD model (*create*, *read*, *update*, *delete*) by way of using standard HTTP verbs (e.g. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`).  Storing the returns of these methods in some sort of session or cookie or otherwise external method (e.g. "give me data for bob", "give me data on businesses", "give me data from my first two queries") goes above and beyond the REST methodology.

The way you'll want to leverage RESTful development is to find ways of combining resources in meaningful ways so as to provide a RESTful environment where the method calls are consistent; `GET` reads data, `POST` creates data, `PUT` updates data, `DELETE` deletes data).

So if you wanted to do something like Steps 1 through 4 I'd recommend something like:

```
GET /user/{userID}/organizations --> {return all affiliated organizations}
GET /user/{userID}/events --> {return all events associated with userID}
GET /organizations/{organization}/events --> {returns all eventID's assoc. with organization}
GET /user/{userID}/savedevents -->  {return all eventID's userID saved to their profile}
GET /events/?eventID=(15,16,20,35,36) --> {return all of the events details for those eventID's}
GET /events/{eventID}--> {return events details for {eventID}}
```

Whereas you might also have:

```
GET /events/  --> {return a complete listing of all event ID's}
GET /events/{userID}  -->  {return all events userID is associated with}
POST /event/  --> {create a new event - ID is assigned by the server}
POST /user/   --> {create a new user - ID is assigned by the server}
PUT /user/{userID}  --> {update/modify user information}
```

Then if you want cross-sectional slices of information, you would have a named resource for the cross section (else pass it as arguments).  Be explicit with your resources (Random FYI, name your resources as nouns only - not verbs).

You also asked:

> To explain further. My hesitation is because I can see how
>   /organizations/123/events is a clean resource; if is identical to
>   saying /events?organizations=123, i.e. "give me resource events where
>   organizations=123". Same for /user/100/organizations.

Essentially both the `named resourced` and the `resource + argument` method can provide the same information.  Typically I have seen RESTful design API call for arguments only when an important delineation is required (range requests, date requests, some REALLY small unit of data, etc.). If you have some higher-order grouping of data that **CAN BE** parsed/introspected further then it's a named resource.  In your example, I'd have it both API calls, as the RESTful spec calls for providing data via multiple paths and by way of using the established HTTP methods.  However, I'd also expand a bit...

```
/events?organizations=123 -->  {return the eventID's associated with org=123}
/organizations/123/events  -->  {return event DETAILS for events associated with org=123}
```

Have a read/go at this, by [Apigee](http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf)

Comment: As an aside, as long as I have been using REST - and I love the fact that it makes it much easier to build and especially understand and use APIs - the discussions around the information and URL architecture never seem to end!

Comment: But to the point: you seem to be arguing that: "events" are their own resource (belong to an org); "users" are their own top-level resource; "organizations" are their own top-level resource. AND if some combination of them is relevant in its own right, e.g. "all the events to which a user has subscribed," and it is complex enough that it cannot be retrieved by `GET /events?user=100` (since the user is not part of the event, then it *is* its own resource: `GET /user/100/events`. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: without diluting the core concepts with implementation specific details, look at it more abstractly.  If I asked you, as a human, what events do you know about?  You would respond, "oh, I know of all these events".  You would extract from your mind all events regardless of date, affiliation, people who might attend... certainly we can go down to that level of granularity, but that's the request - the request is `GET /events/`  Event's are not necessarily belong to an organization, but they can!  They can also belong to a user, or a date... [more to come]

Comment: Events are there own top level resources (they can exists without affiliation to organization or user because events can have under it, abstractly mind you, users and orgs).  Likewise, Organizations exists without events and users and are their own resource, but they can have events and users under it.  Likewise, Users is a resource because they exists without orgs and events, but they can have Orgs and Events associated with it.  It's a matter of perspective.  It's all the same data, just referenced, presented differently, and/or at a finer level of detail based on the resource you access.

Comment: I imagine all of this would be far simpler if an event belonged to a user, but it doesn't. Events to users is many-to-many. So there is a "signup" that maps users to events, and a "registration" that maps users to organizations.

Comment: FWIW, in my model, events **must** belong to an organization. But it is just an aside. I will let you `GET /events/:event` but **not** `POST /events`. You **have** to `POST /organization/:org/events`.

Comment: Exactly.  Again, it's about perspective...  if you want to look at data from the "eyes" of events, then you access the "event" resource.  If you want to look at it through the eyes of a "single user" then access the resource "user", same for organization.

Comment: Which is fine - that's an implementation detail that falls outside the scope of the RESTful methodology domain.

Comment: Have a read of that whitepaper I posted, http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf.  It's oddly half-decent lol.

Comment: I did read through it, as soon as you posted it, no it isn't half bad. It is surprisingly useful as a reference, not just as a beginner's paper.

Comment: to your note about "events have to belong to an org"... that's fine.  But remember, what if a user wants to see all events... are you going to make them go to each Organization resource and type `/organization/{orgname}/events`?  No, you want to provide a larger view by allowing events be a resource that when called shows what events are available.  Now with that said, I don't know exactly what you are building, but if the events are not meant to viewed across orgs because it doesn't make sense, then I'm just rambling (for instance, if you were building a Guild site for an online game [more]..

Comment: Of course not. I also have a top-level (`GET`-only, except for system admins) resource of `GET /event` and `GET /event/:event`

Comment: Lets say you were doing it for World of Warcraft... guilds across servers wouldn't care what events they are putting on because they have no affiliation and/or access to those events... it wouldn't make sense to put events as a top-level resource.. you might embed it under the org or under the server... whereas if you were doing events in a particular city, it would make sense to glob everything under an /events resource.

Comment: ...but I did tick your up one for the detail, and for the great reference.