# REST: Offer detailed and overview response for the same resource

Tags: rest

I have a resource say `rest/users` which contains users with many attributes. Now i want to offer three things.

- An overview which contains every users name and id (to save traffic)
- A detailed view which contains every attribute of a user (to save requests if a client wants all data)
- A single user (via `rest/users/{id}`)

I have two ideas to solve this.

1. Use a query parameter, e.g. view, which can be detail or overview
2. Return the overview when accessing `rest/users` and the detail view when accessing `rest/users/all`

Which one is the RESTful solution? Or is there a better one? Should I maybe avoid offering two responses in the first place?

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate of [architectural design for REST API with views across resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208986/architectural-design-for-rest-api-with-views-across-resources), because want different answers for the same resource, not a combination of different resources.

Lutz Horn answer solved the Problem for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [architectural design for REST API with views across resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208986/architectural-design-for-rest-api-with-views-across-resources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which one is the RESTful solution?

Neither are RESTful. When requesting

```
GET /rest/users
```

you can use [Content Negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) to differentiate between a list for short and a list of detailed users. Making a request for

```
GET /rest/users
Accept: application/vnd.example.com.users.short+json
```

would return a JSON representation of the list of *short user information*, a request for

```
GET /rest/users
Accept: application/vnd.example.com.users.detailed+json
```

would return a JSON representation of the list of *users with all details*.

Note that I made up the MIME types in the `Accept` headers. The important part is `vnd` which is the standard way to define your own MIME types based on existing ones (`application/json` in this case).

**Don't** use query parameters or different URLs to differentiate because you are requesting *the same resource* (list of users) *in different representations* (short and detailed). The URLs is the same for both, the `Accept` headers are different.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you, always wondering how to implement it RESTful way. Do you have any link to documentation where is written that this solution is RESTful?

Comment: No link, sorry. But if you think a little about the [Uniform Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Uniform_interface) of REST, I think it becomes obvious that this approach is RESTful.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer! I didn't think about using different headers, but it makes much more sense than my solutions.